# WebService Prestashop not show values fields

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

When I retrieve a customer, this return me all fields of customer, but the values is not show!
My code:

```
$opt['resource'] = 'customers';
        $opt['id'] = '1';
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);
        dump($xml);die();
```

[image]

Comment: It returns an XML, you should then parse it via SimpleXML or any other XML parser to get those values

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML can read the values for you:

```
$opt['resource'] = 'customers';
$opt['id'] = '1';
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$loadedXML = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

You can then access the values by their names:

```
$loadedXML->id_default_group
```